# AWS: Credits Dropping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

About a year ago I created an AWS account for an assignment.

I then forgot about it.

30 days ago I got an email saying that my account is about to expire, and that I have $11 credits left.

"That's weird, I don't remember being so low on credits, but oh well, as long as nothing is running its fine"

Then today happened, and I got another email; Yeah, another "friendly reminder" that my account will expire, but this time, something's different, instead of having $11 credits, now I have $9.

"Oh shoot" I said, and quickly got into AWS to check that nothing was running in EC2, and indeed, nothing was.

But I still don't know why my credits dropped, how long have they been dropping for? And what will happen when they get to $0?

They have my card info, will I get charged?

I would've closed the account but they say that once I do, I'll never be able to use that email to open an account again so... I don't wanna try that just yet.

So how can I figure out why my credits been dropping?

Should I pull the trigger and close off the account?

H E L P - P L Z ! ! !

Comment: > will I get charged?

Maybe, yes.

You can see billing information in https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/ . I recommend confirming it.

Answer (score 2):

In the AWS management console, click the Account menu in the top-right corner (next to the region name). The select **My Billing Dashboard**.

Click **Bill Details** to see exactly where the costs originated.

If you still had an Amazon EC2 instance that was stopped, there would be charges for the Amazon EBS storage. You might also have content in Amazon S3. It will details all the charges.

If you continue using services and you have no remaining credits, your charges will be billed to your credit card.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot to mention that, I actually did checked the billing section but it has nothing, even the downloadable csv shows nothing, as for storage, I deleted the instances long ago, and the only thing left is the default security group (Which can't be deleted), and S3 doesn't seem to have anything... bummer.

Comment: Then where are you seeing the credit balance? Can you provide a screenshot, or the exact wording?

Comment: Thanks for your attention so far, here's the image of the 2 emails and the billing section - https://www.mediafire.com/view/fhj1mijdylgzk4o

Comment: It appears that you are using an AWS Educate Starter Account, which is a [program](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/) where educational institutions provide AWS accounts with credit. It appears that your account expires next month, so it won't matter anyway.